# ifconfig displays public IP address

Tags: ip, ip-address, ifconfig, private-ip

I've logged via `ssh` to remote host. When I type `ifconfig` output contains:

```
ens160: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 106.120.101.39  netmask 255.255.255.128  broadcast 106.120.101.127
```

IP address `106.120.101.39` does not belong to reserved private address pool, so how it possible that it's displayed while invoking `ifconfig`? As far as I know `ifconfig` displays only private addresses.

Comment: It's not uncommon for a webserver to have a public IP like that.

Comment: ifconfig will show the addresses that the host has configured.  So whatever is happening, that host does have that address configured for the interface. 
Is there another interface listed that has an internal address?

Comment: @RLines, yes. That's not the only one

Comment: If it is being assigned that address by dhcp or some other system then that is the address for the host.  Why are you expecting it to have a private address? 
ifconfig doesn't differentiate between public/private, it only shows the address that is configured.

Comment: I was wrong. Tkanks